# mocking db cursor and asserting values passed to cursor's functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

In my source class I have the following statements

```
    def main():
        conn = create_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
```

In my test class , I am trying to assert the the "query" passed to cur.execute method. But I would like to mock both create_connection and the cursor object returned by cursor() function. I was able to mock create_connection using the code below. How can I patch cursor and assert the value of query passed to execute function?

```
    @patch(main.create_connection)
    def test_main(self,mock_conn):
```

Comment: mock_conn is a Mock object, you can configure it to have whatever attributes you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the created cursor is already a mock (e.g. each call to a mock object creates another mock object), you don't have to configure anything else. You can just get the cursor mock:

```
@patch('main.create_connection')
def test_main(mock_conn):
    cursor = mock_conn.return_value.cursor.return_value
    main()
    cursor.execute.assert_called_once_with(query)
```